# Search function not working properly

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to make a search based on my categories in a Cognito Form and it gives me a bunch of different things, but not all the entries of the searched categories.
The search function that was previously properly working seem to be off...

Answer (score 1):

In a recent release, Cognito Forms updated the search system to more closely align with the experience users have come to expect for modern search engines.  This means that it will split search terms and look for all entries that have each term entered somewhere on the entry.

Including support for searching by a phrase will be included in the next release.  There is a [card](https://trello.com/c/h8pReWK5) on the [idea board](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board) where you can more closely follow the release of this feature.

Disclaimer: I'm an Engineer on the Cognito Forms team

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that my entries are listed in categories like "Avant 1", "Avant 2", "Avant 3", etc. If I make a search on "Avant 2" for exemple, it will give me all "Avant" disregarding the digit ans also, it's making the search only on the last 17 entries in my list, not the whole 207 entries. Thank you.

Comment: @Hugues, we are rolling out an update as I write this that will allow you to specifically search for phrases using quotes.  So, for example, you could search for: "Avent 1" truck and the system will return all forms with the exact phrase "Avent 1" and the word "truck".  I will look into the 17 entry search limit you described.